# Scroll while dragging with DragImage

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop, monomac, xamarin.mac

I'm trying to drag a view to another, I'm using **DragImage method** to pass data to my destination(another view), everything works fine, but while I'm dragging its container does not scroll.

the hierarchy:

```
NSWindow
   NSScrollView
           NSView -> NSScrollView's Document
                 NSViews -> NSView's subViews -> Drag and Drop between them.
```

I need to pass event 
Any idea how to fix it?